# Django relation different models to one

Tags: django, django-models

I use django 4.2 and want to relate some document models to a few other models.

If I use only once model I do it like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    file = models.FileField()
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name='documents')
```

And I can get all docs for MyModel instance.

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get()
docs = instance.documents
```

What is the best practice to do it with a few models?

Ex:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

class MySecondModel(models.Model):
    ...

class MyThirdModel(models.Model):
    ...

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    file = models.FileField()
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel, related_name='documents', null=True)
    my_second_model = models.ForeignKey(MySecondModel, related_name='documents', null=True)
    my_third_model = models.ForeignKey(MyThirdModel, related_name='documents', null=True)
```

It looks overhead. Besides Document instance will be relate to only once of these models and other will be null.

Of course I can create 3 different models for Documents like MyModelDocument, MySecondModelDocument, MyThirdModelDocument. But it also looks like overhead because we will have 3 the same models to store files in 3 different tables in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's go with two different models and all need a `ForeignKey` to `Document`model.

This can be done by subclassing. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) about your general subclassing choices.

Second mentioned option is the only possibility for your usecase I guess: [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). This option does allow your common model to be created standalone and creates a database table for the common model.

```py
class CommonModel(models.Model):
    ...

class DifferentOne(CommonModel):
    ...

class DifferentTwo(CommonModel):
    ...

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    file = models.FileField()
    my_model = models.ForeignKey(CommonModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='documents')
```

As I said `CommonModel` has now its own database table. This makes perfect sense, because by design of `ForeignKey` it is not allowed to point to more than one single hit in **one** database table. If your different models do not have a common database table you would have a pointer to one single hit in **two** database tables. That's not easily if at all possible as far as I know.

Having said that: If you don't want to have that relationship as a result of the inheritance, you should then stick to your initial approach.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this with more descriptive model names: `Owner`model and `Document`model.

One specific `Owner` can have multiple `Document`s. 
One specific `Document` can have only one specific `Owner`. 
That is one classic [Many to One](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) example. Here one would use `ForeignKey`.

Going with this example you give the [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) field to the `Document`. Because the `ForeignKey` holds then the one single identification number, key, uuid or whatever for that one specific related `Owner`.

```py
class Owner(models.Model):
    ...

class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    file = models.FileField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now you can do the lookups quite easily starting from the `Document`.

```py
doc = Document.objects.all().first()  # grab one document
print(doc.owner)  # outputs print/string representation of related owner
```

If you want to do it the other way round, starting from the `Owner` we are talking about a set of `Document`s, because - remember - one `Owner` can be assigned to multiple `Document`s. The phrasing "Set of `Document`s" already leads you to the django syntax by the way.

```py
own = Owner.objects.all().first()  # grab one Owner
for d in own.document_set.all():
    print(d)
```

This is called reverse lookup. As you perfectly figured out yourself, it is therefore not needed to create multiple models of the same object. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) you'll find more examples. Search for "_set" to find the reverse lookup examples quicker.

Comment: The Django "magic" reverse relation `xxx_set` is often somewhat confusing. I always prefer an explicit related_name on the ForeignKey.

Comment: Hi! I know how to use FK relation between two models. My question about relate 3 different models (example owner/person/user) to one model Document